# Quotient rule of radicals - cannot get to correct answer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to simplify the following expression:

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{(9a^5b^{14})}}{\sqrt{(3a^4b^5)}}$$

The solution is given:

$$b^4\sqrt{3ab}$$

I was unable to recreate this solution. Here's where I got to. Using the quotient rule I rewrote the expression as:

$$\sqrt{\dfrac{9a^5b^{14}}{3a^4b^5}}$$

Then, I attempted to simplify (the radicand?):

$$\dfrac{9a^5b^{14}}{3a^4b^5}$$

Becomes $\sqrt{3ab^9}$.

My train of thought is that first, I simplify $9a^5 / 3a^4$ to just $3a$. Is that right?

Next I tried to simplify $b^{14} / b^5$ to $b^9$

Thus I arrived at $\sqrt{3ab^9}$

Where did I go wrong and am I on the right track?

Comment: You can use curly brackets to include multiple characters within a radical.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, added now

Comment: No problem. Also, you can also use \frac{}{} to show fractions, such as $\frac{a}{b}$, which is typically preferred to using a slash, like $a/b$. (Of course, you don’t need to edit the post. Just pointing out.)

Comment: Noted with thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$\sqrt{3ab^9}=(\sqrt{3a})(b^\frac92)=b^4\sqrt{3ab}$$

Comment: Thank you for answering but I'm struggling to follow. Why $b^{9/2}$?

Comment: Because $\sqrt b = b^{\frac{1}{2}}$, so $\sqrt{b^9} = b^{\frac{9}{2}}$. In general, we have $\sqrt[n] {b^m} = b^{\frac{m}{n}}$.

Comment: Thank you but I still struggle to see. How did you complete the last step, to go from $b^{9/2}$ to $b^4$

Comment: It’s the reverse process: $$b^{\frac{9}{2}} = b^4\cdot b^{\frac{1}{2}} = b^4\cdot\sqrt{b}$$ In fact, as seen, your answer isn’t even wrong, it’s just not fully simplified.

Comment: @DougFir $b^9=b^8\cdot b$, and $\sqrt{b^8}=b^4$. So you can take $b^4$ outside the radical and leave the remaining $b$ inside.

Answer (score 3):

$b^9= (b^8)b= (b^4)^2b$ so $\sqrt{b^9}= \sqrt{(b^4)^2}\sqrt{b}= b^4\sqrt{b}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write $$\sqrt{\frac{9a^5b^{14}}{3a^4b^5}}=\sqrt{3ab^9}=\sqrt{3ab^9}=b^4\sqrt{3ab}$$

Comment: $\sqrt {3ab^9}=\sqrt {3ab^9}?$

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan He is not wrong

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout I am forced to agree.